# Genetic Algorithm for Decision Trees

Tags: python, simulation, decision-tree, genetic-algorithm

I made a natural selection simulator in pygame where there are ten characters that each take in sensor inputs that are fed into a decision tree (with randomly initialized nodes) and tell them to either move left, move right, or jump. Their fitness is calculated based on the amount of food they are able to eat subtracted the max amount of time they spend not eating (calculated by pythons time.time() function). Food is spawned in at a random location every time one of the characters eats one. After a generation ends, my program picks the character with the highest fitness score and put them in the next generation without any mutations. I then randomly select 9 more characters from the previous generation and there is a 15% chance that they will have mutations. Mutations in this case mean that the characters decision tree will have the values in a random node being randomly assigned a new value. This seems like a standard genetic algorithm, but when I run it for over a thousand generations, there seems to be no improvement and even some slightly diminished fitness. I don't know what is wrong.
[image: This is a graph of the highest fitness value for each generation for when I ran the program for over 1000 generations.]

I looked up articles on how to do genetic algorithms for binary decision trees and followed their algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As an algorithm for simulating natural selection this has many strange decisions:

- Players that move onto the next round are technically offsprings of previous players. So then why are the offsprings of the most fit individual exempt from mutations? There's a reason they are called "random mutations" because they happen randomly and the chance should be exactly the same for all players.
- Your sampling method is strange. For the next generation you pick the most fit player and 9 randoms. Why? The most fit player is most likely to produce children so his offsprings should be overrepresented in the subsequent generations. This is the key principle of Natural Selection. You should do weighted sampling based on the fitness score.
- 10 players per generation is too few. Especially given the chance of mutation of 15%. Mutation is as likely to reduce fitness of an individual as it is to increase the fitness.